# Bundling css/js only in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way to make MVC4's bundling system include scripts/styles *only* in debug mode?

For example, I have lots of debug mode scripts which help me debug my system. I obviously don't want them rendered when the system is in release mode.

I thought of using a block like:

```
  bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("mybundle")
    .Include(
      "~/scripts/foo.js",
      "~/scripts/bar.js"
      #if DEBUG
      ,"~/scripts/baz-debug.js"
      #endif
    )
  );
```

but debug mode should be controlled via `web.config`.

So what is the correct approach?

Comment: This link may be able to help you <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487742/asp-net-mvc4-bundling-minification-min-js-files-excluded-from-scripts-render>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if debugging is enabled you can use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

provided that the HttpContext is accessible. If not, the longer approach would be this one:

```
var isDebug =(System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/compilation").Debug;
```

Both these suggestions come from this article: [How do I check if Debug is enabled in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542875/how-do-i-check-if-debug-is-enabled-in-web-config).

What I would do to actually add modules conditionally would be to start off by creating a `Dictionary<string, bool>` of script paths and whether or not they should be added in release mode.

When you call the program, if debugging is false then simply filter the dictionary into a collection of elements:

```
var includes = dict.Where(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key);
```

And then pass the result to your `Include` statement.

Comment: Where would you perform the check for the `IsDebuggingEnabled`? The bundling system is initially registered in the `global.asax.cs` I think, so would you do it there? Is the context already alive that early in the pipeline?

Comment: Unless you need this data elsewhere I would do it right before the compiling of the includes.